# How to place the output jar into another folder with maven?

Tags: maven, jar

I'd like to place my output jar and jar-with-dependencies into another folder (not in `target/` but in `../libs/`).

How can I do that?

Comment: One little Maven tip - don't fight it's preferences, it'll drive you insane :). But you can always use something like the ant plugin do do basically everything you want, like copying at the end of the build from target to ../libs...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the *outputDirectory* parameter of the maven-jar-plugin for this purpose:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>../libs</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But as cdegroot wrote, you should probably better not fight the maven way.

Comment: Maybe it's better to copy jars instead of moving them?

Comment: By the book I strongly suggest using the maven-dependency-plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to resolve inter-module dependencies (If you need to transfer to a different module).

Comment: You should never use maven-dependency-plugin to use it as a dependency for inter module dependencies. Usually you can simply define a dependency this works...if that does not work there some other issue in your build...

Comment: @Torsten It puts the jar into outputDirectory and proguard isn't able to find jar to obfuscate. How to make this work with proguard-maven-plugin?

Comment: @gaurav I suggest that you ask this question in a separate post as this is not related to the original question. Thisway it is also easier to find for others. I personally have no experience with the proguard plugin.

Comment: why not fight the maven way? what's disadvantageous about this solution?

Answer (score 47):

If you want to copy the artifact into a directory outside your project, solutions might be:

- `maven-jar-plugin` and configure `outputDirectory`
- `maven-antrun-plugin` and copy task
- `copy-maven-plugin` by Evgeny Goldin

Example for the `copy-maven-plugin` is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-to-local-directory</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipIdentical>false</skipIdentical>
                <failIfNotFound>false</failIfNotFound>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <description>Copy artifact to another directory</description>
                        <targetPath>/your/local/path</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This plugin is lacking in documentation.

Comment: This plugin does not work as is, it throws the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem`

Comment: It is not true that the path in outputDirectory must be relative.

Comment: @ACV You are right! `outputDirectory` is simply a File as can be seen in the [source](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-jar-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java?view=markup). I edited my answer.

Comment: Can this place jars into the remote server?

Answer (score 25):

Another way would be [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) (find the current version here):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-files-on-build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/[TO-DIR]</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>[FROM-DIR]</directory>
                        <!--<include>*.[MIME-TYPE]</include>-->
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this doesn't copy across on the first build, only on subsequent ones

Comment: @minseong I've tried it and it worked pretty well. Maybe you have some eclipse-maven lifecycle mapping problem?

Comment: @minseong pretty sure that's because the phase that it runs on is `validate`. You can change it to `package` or `install` to have it work on the first build as well.

Comment: Update `<phase>validate</phase>` to `<phase>install</phase>` or `<phase>package</phase>`

Comment: I think `<phase>install</phase>` worked for me like I wanted it to.

Comment: I need to give the copied artifact a different name, but it is not clear that this is possible using maven-resources-plugin.

Comment: I think it's the most concise one ⭐ It just works, and doesn't require much configuration. @Stefan there is but a small problem: need to specify `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>`, otherwise it can't find the stuff.

Comment: In case you need to copy the SpringBoot repackaged jar, replace package phase with install, and run mvn install to copy the jar.

Answer (score 17):

I would do it this way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy file="target/${project.artifactId}-exec.jar" tofile="../../docker/${project.artifactId}.jar"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

This technique worked well for me:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Second to the maven-assembly-plugin technique I found this to be the simplest and most mainstream solution, since assembly-plugin requires an additional descriptor file.

Comment: In this case giving the context from the <root> element of the `pom.xml` made it easier for me to include in my own `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I specially like the solution using `maven-resources-plugin` (see [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)) because is already included in maven, so no extra download is needed, and also is very configurable to do the copy at a specific phase of your project (see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#build-the-project) to learn & **understand** about *phases*). And the best part of this approach is that it won't mess up any previous processes or build you had before :)

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/dir/where/you/want/to/put/jar</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>/dir/where/you/have/the/jar</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                  <includes>
                     <include>file-you-want-to.jar</include>
                     <include>another-file-you-want-to.jar</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Of course you can also use interpolated variables like `${baseDir}` and other good stuff like that all over your XML. And you could use wild cards as they explain [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependency plugin is perfectly capable of copying all dependencies and just built artifact in a custom location. Following example will copy all runtime dependencies and a built artifact in a two execution phases.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>                     
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jars</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-artifact</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jars</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

While documentation of dependency plugin states in its documentation that in order to copy built artifact you have to use any phase after the package phase, that is not true if you are building jars. In that situation you can use package phase. At least in 3.3.0 version of plugin.