# Maven changing output directory for jar doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, jar, eclipse-plugin

I build my project with `mvn clean install`, however I want to generate a subfolder in the target folder and put the generated jar file in there. I saw these two questions [Maven: specify the outputDirectory only for packaging a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar) and [maven: how to place the output jar into another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689511/maven-how-to-place-the-output-jar-into-another-folder) however their answer doesn't seem to work.

This is how my maven build looks like:

```
   <build>
        <plugins>       
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/blah</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

However I get the .jar file still in target directory. I also noticed that the project packaging is set as `<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>` if I change this to jar, then it works fine, however I do need it to be `eclipse-plugin`. I am also using `tycho` for the eclipse plugin. Am I missing something that was not mentioned before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your packaging of `eclipse-plugin` I'm guessing you're using Tycho.  Tycho doesn't seem to use any of the maven plugins, so configuring the `maven-jar-plugin` isn't going to help.  Instead try configuring the [`tycho-packaging-plugin`](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/package-plugin-mojo.html), specifically the [`buildDirectory`](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/package-plugin-mojo.html#buildDirectory) property:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tycho-version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/blah</buildDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```